# How does it works the transfer of a LINQ result to memory? What about chained LINQ queries?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

**First Scenario:** How i get queries into memory.

```
var query_1 = DbContext.Entity1.Where(x=> x.Id == 1); 
// returns an IEnumerable. I'm not sure, and thus i'm asking, that everytime that
//query_1 is called the query will be executed again, so @query_1 works just as a
//reference to a query.
var query_2 = DbContext.Entity1.Where(x=> x.Id == 1).ToArray(); 
// returns an array of IEnumerable. Once again i only suppose that this one will store
//the result of the query in an array, therefore, in memory, and so would work using
//'ToDictionary' and 'ToList' (i'm not sure regarding 'ToLookup' as i haven't used it).
```

If any of the statements are incorrect feel free to correct them.

**Second Scenario:** What happens with chained queries that i didn't try to get into memory.

Using *@query_1*

```
var query_3 = query_1.First().NavigationProperty1.Where(y=> y.RandomProperty == 3);
```

I assume that once i call @query_3, and whenever i'll do that, it will generate a query to be executed in that moment because @query_1 was not stored in memory, it's just a reference.

Am i correct? If there are any other ways to storage the results in memory i'd be glad to hear.

**EDIT**

```
var query_1 = DbContext.Entity1.Where(x => x.Id == 71); 
// query_1 is a SQL statement
var query_2 = DbContext.Entity1.Where(x => x.Id == 71).First(); 
// query_2 is a 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' which i believe it's the data in memory
var query_2_1 = query_2.NavigationProperty1.Where(x => x.Name == ""); 
// query_2_1 is a 'System.Linq.IENumerable' and i'm not sure it's in memory
var query_3 = DbContext.Entity1.Where(x => x.Id == 71).ToArray(); 
// query_3 is an Array of 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'
var query_4 = DbContext.Entity1.Single(x => x.Id == 71);
// query_4 is the same as query_2
```

Considering that 'ToArray' is an array of 'SystemDynamicProxies', that means query_2, query_3 and query_4 were stored in memory.

But i'm not sure about query_2_1. It's not an SQL statement but i don't think' i can say that if it's not so that means it's in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is Eager Loading Vs Lazy Loading.

When you create your Linq query1 it defines the query but it will not execute the query until you use the var Query_1 in another statement that requires a value.   This is Lazy Loading where we want to saves the execution until the values are needed.

for example query1.First(); Is Eager Loading.  We force the execution by requiring data.

In Query_2 you are calling ToArray which forces the query to execute.  (Eager Loading)

In Query3 your are calling .First() which will fire the query because you are asking for data.  (Eager Loading)

You can also call the following to load the data in your example:

.FirstOrDefault()
.Count()
.ElementAt(1)
etc etc...

Comment: Hmmmm i see. So in the case i assign Query_4 = Query_1.First(); and then Query_5 = Query_4.Where(x=> SomeHashset.Contains(x.Id)) i can assume that Query_5 will be executed over Query_4, which is an object in memory and the usage of a HashSet will be useful in matters of performance?

Joel's answer states that .First() is an Extension Method and won't fire a query, just add more lines to the SQL extension that is assigned to that variable, and suggested me a test to confirm that, this one that i'll make soon.

Answer (score 2):

You do have some of the terms and concepts a little mixed up, and I'll try to inject corrections where I think they belong:

In query_1, saying it returns an `IEnumerable` is accurate and inaccurate at the same time. It refers to a sequence reference that will ultimately produce an `IQueryable` (which implements `IEnumerable`), but because of its context it won't actually produce the sequence until something is called on it to execute. If you were to run the debugger on this set of code, when you hover the mouse over query_1, you would see a SQL statement instead of an object enumeration.

In query_2, you have added the `.ToArray()` method call which is an instruction to transfer the sequence into an `IEnumerable` held in local memory. This forces the statement to execute and so while query_1 remains as an unexecuted sequence, query_2 actually lives in memory after it has run.

Any LINQ extension method applied to query_1 will continue to add to the expression tree of the sequence without executing it. So a statement like:

```
var count = DbContext.Entity1.Where(x=> x.Id == 1).Select(x =>x.ID).Count();
// At this point "count" is still an unexecuted sequence. 
// It knows that it will be an int, but it doesn't know the value yet
var someCountingInteger = count + 7; 
// At this line, a mathematical operator is called in memory
// that forces the sequence to execute. Now it lives in memory.
```

This is not a statement you'd really want to have because some of it is pointless, but even though there are 3 extension method calls here, the sequence simply continues to get altered but never called until something is executed on it.

So when you consider your version of query_3, it still only generates an expression tree for the sequence. It won't be executed until some other code comes along and requires information from it.

```
var query_3 = query_1.First().NavigationProperty1.Where(y=> y.RandomProperty == 3);
// At this point, nothing has been executed, and if you
// put your mouse over query_3 it should show you a SQL statement

var listOfThings = query_3.ToList();
// Now, we've called ToList and it gets executed and stored in local memory
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, yes, i do often mix things up, i'm learning it on the go, i'm on my current job for 1.5 years now and i had none experience with C# or LINQ back then so i lack a lot of fundamentals.

Although i didn't mention the IQueryable i'm aware of this behavior, i was told that until i call it to List, Array or such it's just a reference, so even though i couldn't phrase it the right way, i've been using LINQ in the right way.

My only doubt concerns to your last example. Nathan's answer states that when i call 'First()' a db call is made and now i'm working in memory, is it accurate?

Comment: @v1n1akabozo: No, a `First()` call is still an extension method building onto the expression tree. An empirical way to test this would be to have a series of lines in a small project that assign to variables, then go line-by-line until you see a variable populated with something other than a SQL statement.

Comment: Yes, good idea, i can do this test and then edit my question with the results. So any extension method will only edit and add more content to the SQL statement that is assigned to that value right? And calling a method to turn the results into c# structures (and in this explanation i'm probably using some wrong words or concepts, but i hope you can understand the message)is the only way to start working with those sets in memory?

Comment: @v1n1akabozo: Not just any extension method, any LINQ extension method that adds to the expression tree.

Comment: .First() is returning the same type as ToArray(), not SQL. I just edited the question

Answer (score 1):

**First Scenario**

While it is true that query_1 is an implicit IEnumerable{T}, it's more important that it returns an actual IQueryable{T}. Any call you make on an IQueryable, until it's truly converted to only an IEnumerable, is added to an underlying Expression, and is not called against the data source nor are any results stored in memory.  Once you make an Executing call (such as ToArray(), First(), Single(), etc), the IQueryable's Expression is converted to a SQL call, and the results are placed in an IEnumerable.

So to answer your question, calling your query_1 statement does not make any db calls, but only stored the prepared Expression for later execution.  Calling your query_2 statement does make a DB call every time, since ToArray is an Executing call.

**Second Scenario**

Once Execution hits the **First()** method, the DB call is made, and you working with local data.  If referencing NavigationProperty1 works, its because you are using Lazy Loading and more DB calls are made to download those references.  In other words, it's a very inefficient use of Entities.

Instead, you'd want to write it like this:

```
var query_3 = query_1.NavigationProperty1.Where(y=> y.RandomProperty == 3).First();
```

That way, the WHERE clause is added to the original DB, and you only make the call once.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i understand what you said, but i guess i wasn't clear enough. I know that calling the property 'Id' might imply that we're working with unique keys, but let's say that query_1 returns me a set with a lot of elements, in this case i cannot call it's navigation property until i focus on a single element of the set. So i'm a little bit confused by your approach. I'm sorry if i'm missing any basic concepts, but a year ago i had 0 experience witch C# and i'm learning on the go hahaha.